# Find how many instances of a word can be made from the chars in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Hello I had a python quize few days ago and there was a question which I was unable to do. It was to find frequency of a word in string or how many times that words comes in the string. Can someone please help me how can we do this like any idea how to accomplish it.

```
Input string: "casortdhgeujcode"
Find: code

Output: 2
```

Some more example string maybe : "hlelo" for hello, "cawodofenkv" for code, etc

I don't have any idea how to start this please help.

Comment: Why is that supposed to be 2?

Comment: How does `code` appear twice in your input?

Comment: It seems `code` appears two times as a subsequence rather than a substring.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Since you have not yet researched the algorithm nor attempted to code the problem yourself, you do not yet have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: What do you want this string to return "caoadae" 1 or 0?
And what about this string? "ccaooaddaee" ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to find the letters 'c' 'o' 'd' 'e' in order in the string.  Your post does not make that clear, and you haven't discussed any attempt or approach, let alone shown the code and error that you have.  This is not a coding or homework service.

Comment: Code appears 2 times in the string that's why 2. It should work if use something else too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = "casortdhgeujcode"
key = "code"
frequency = {}

for c in key:
    frequency[c] = string.count(c)
    
print(min(frequency.values()))
```

Comment: Actually it does work if you use my my example string but it just doesn't work for anything else... Like "hlello", etc

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I mean what if if have to find Hello in "Hlelo" or code in "cawodofenkv"

Comment: Oh, I thought it had to be in order. If you make a new post with the more specific requirements, I'll write that algorithm for you

Comment: Oh Thank you I am doing it wait

Comment: Oh sorry it looks like I won't be able to question for few minutes. Can you do something else?

Comment: Sir?? I there any other way you help me.

Comment: Is that answer good for you?

Comment: Sir this indeed works but it takes a lot of time to execute I mean if the string length increase. What you think?

Comment: Let me think, I'm not sure which part is inefficient, I suspect it's using string.count() 4 times

Comment: So you there could be a better a way?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's time complexity can be lower than O(n*m), where n is the string and m is the key, or at least I don't know how to do it. It works instantly for me even with huge inputs. If you are reading from a file, then it will naturally take longer. Sorry I can't help you any further

Comment: No problem, good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
input_string = "casortdhgeujcode"
find = "code"
new_string = ""

for item in input_string:
    if item in find:
        new_string += item
print (new_string.count(find))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

One straight forward way is to count the number of times each letter appears in the string and use the minimum value. For example --

```
string = "casortdhgeujcode"
lst = []

for letter in "code":
   c = string.count(letter)
   lst.append(c)

num_times = min(lst)

print(num_times)
2
```

Comment: What about "eeeeeeeddddddddoooooooccccccccc"?

Comment: Yes it does work for this specific string but what if put something else.